# How to import objects in javscript/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Suppose i have a file : **main2.js**

```
exports.obj = {

x : 10,
setX : function (y)
{
    this.x = y;
},
getX : function()
{
    return this.x;
}
};
```

Having  2 files:-   **abc.js**

```
  const obj = require("./main2").obj;
  describe("Test", function(){

  it("Set X", () => {
  obj.setX(50);

 })
})
```

**def.js**

```
  const obj = require("./main2").obj;
  describe("Test", function(){

  it("Get X", () => {
  console.log(obj.getX());

 })
})
```

When i ran both files together, getting **50 as output**, but expected 10 as output i.e needed both the file should have different instance of obj, how to achieve it

Comment: Why do you expect 10, you're using the setter with val 50 `obj.setX(50);` isn't it?

Comment: try `const { obj } = new (require("./main2"))` or without destructoring: `const obj = new (require("./main2").obj)`

Comment: Either clone the object on import or alternatively export a function that creates separate instances of this object. The latter seems preferable to me - you'd have to export something like `makeObj` and then call it which will produce independent copies

Comment: @MaximilianFixl there is a single object that's just referred to from two places. OP seems to expect there to be two different objects when importing multiple times.

Comment: @MaximilianFixl the OP wants to have seperate instances instead of a reference to the exported object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use require you're getting a singlenton instance, so the second call is returning the same value as first.
You have to export a factory function. Ex:

```
exports.generateObj = function(){
  return {
    x : 10,
    setX : function (y)
    {
        this.x = y;
    },
    getX : function()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
  }
};
```

And change the others .js with:

```
const obj = require("./main2").generateObj();
```

instead of:

```
const obj = require("./main2").obj;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a single object with couple of references to the same object.
If you want to have a different object everytime, you may want to use a function or a class that will return this object.

Should look like this:

**main2.js**

```js
exports.obj = function() {
  return {
    x : 10,
    setX : function (y) {
      this.x = y;
    },
    getX : function() {
      return this.x;
    }
  };
};
```

and then change other files to use `const obj = require("./main2").obj()`

Answer (score 0):

maybe another solution would be to unexpose x

filea.js

//Module.exports allow you to export the function without naming it

```
module.exports = () =>{// or module.exports = function(){
  let x=10;

function setX(i){
  x=i;
}

function getX(){
  return x;
}
  return {getX,setX}
}
```

fileb.js

```
const myPseudoClass= require('./fila');
const obj = myPseudoClass();
// can be replaced by const obj = require('./fila')();
console.log('x=',obj.getX());
obj.setX(50);
console.log('x=',obj.getX());
```